# SwiftUI Textfield - How to set the background Color for textfield in edit mode to clear

Tags: swiftui, textfield

To fit in with my other controls, my TextField views have frames which have a larger height than the text itself.

The standard view is shown in the top of the image with a custom placeholder.

When I tap on the TextField, the smaller text area itself has a gray background, as shown in the bottom of the image.

[image: TextView example]

How do I set this text background to a clear color?

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var city: String
    @State var street: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                if city.isEmpty { Text("Bitte Namen eingeben")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(Color( red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 0.3))
                }
            TextField("", text: self.$city)
                .textFieldStyle(CustomTFStyle())
            }
            
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                if street.isEmpty { Text("Bitte Strasse eingeben")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(Color( red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 0.3))
                }
            TextField("", text: self.$street)
                .textFieldStyle(CustomTFStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct CustomTFStyle : TextFieldStyle {
    public func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .accentColor(.black)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 70, alignment: .center)
                .border(Color.gray, width: 4)
             .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .shadow(radius: 12)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Reiner, i just tested your code - but never saw your gray background...how can i reproduce it?

Comment: Run the code, click in one of the textfields and enter text

Comment: which iOS Version r u testing?

Comment: i would assume you are testing 13.2....in 13.0 and 13.3 the gray color is not showing up with your example

Comment: testing with iOS 13.0

Comment: in 13.0 this did not happen to me....do you have special settings set? special display contrast or something like that?

Comment: I just updated to Xcode 11.3 and the behavior is still there. I'm working with the IPAD pro (11inch) Simulator, switched off all keyboard functions and tested with the Xcode  Appearance Settings "custom, light and dark mode".

Enclosed you find a link for a small video with the behavior.

https://youtu.be/OGxJ_Tikgs4

What are your settings?

Comment: but you know that xcdoe appearance has nothing to do with dark mode in app?

Comment: we believe that the problem is happening to you, but honestly: do you really test with the code you gave us? Did you change any !? simulator appearance/visual settings?

Comment: Your hint about the code brought me to the solution. Of course, the code of the view is part of an larger project, so i copied the code to a new clean project and everything worked fine.

In the RootController i set the appearance of the navigation Bar and  the scrollviews with a init().. Uncommenting the line  "UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = .lightGray" brought the solution. I didn't know that this does also effect the Textfield behavior.

Comment: would be nice if you then could upvote my comment....and i am glad i could help you ;)

Comment: Hi Chris, i'm totally sorry, but it looks like i cannot upvote because i do not have the neccessary points. Is there another chance of upvoting?

Comment: I don‘t think so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = .lightGray" in the init method of my rootview does also effect the Textfield behavior. Deleting this line did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to reproduce this. Try cleaning your project and quitting/restarting Xcode.

Try adding the modifier to your `CustomTFStyle`:

```
.background(Color.clear)
```

*Sidenote:* 
You also may want to consider assigning an `AttributedString` as a placeholder instead of conditionally ZStack'ing a separate `Text` on top of the `TextField`

For that you will need to wrap an `UITextField` in a `UIViewRepresentable` and do the classic work inside the `makeUIView` method.

Comment: I cleaned the project, deleted the derived data folder and restarted Xcode.

I tested it with the Canvas, the iphone11 and the IPAD Pro simulator and on a real device. As soon as i click in the textfield, it shows a gray background.
I deleted the Textfieldstyle and the behavior is still there. I'm working with Xcode 11.2.1 and catalina 10.15.1.

@Jordan I considered the sidenote also, but because i want to get used to swiftUi, i was looking only for SwiftUI solutions.